# Using ProjectDelegate `gradle` within the `plugins` DSL

Tags: gradle-kotlin-dsl

As titled, this:

```
plugins {
   if (gradle.gradleVersion < "6.0")
      id("ru.vyarus.quality").version("4.3.0")
}
```

returns:

> Unresolved reference: gradle

`gradle` is also marked as an error, and hovering the mouse above I get:

> 'val Build_gradle.gradle: Gradle' can't be called in this context by implicit receiver. Use the explicit one if necessary

Googling around, I tried specifying the receiver:

```
plugins {
   if (this@Build_gradle.gradle.gradleVersion < "6.0")
      id("ru.vyarus.quality").version("4.3.0")
}
```

But it fires:

> Unresolved reference: getGradle

Is there a way? (other than declaring an outside variable just for that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Limitations of the plugins DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#plugins_dsl_limitations):

> This requires that plugins be specified in a way that Gradle can easily and quickly extract, before executing the rest of the build script. It also requires that the definition of plugins to use be somewhat static.

> The `plugins {}` block does not support arbitrary code. It is constrained, in order to be idempotent (produce the same result every time) and side effect free (safe for Gradle to execute at any time).

In fact, your build script is evaluated against `CompiledKotlinPluginsBlock` for the `plugins` block, and `CompiledKotlinBuildScript` for the rest. So `this@Build_gradle` doesn't always refer to the same object. You can see this by printing the superclass at different places:

```
println(this@Build_gradle::class.java.superclass)
```

And as it turns out `CompiledKotlinPluginsBlock` doesn't have a `getGradle()` method.

It's great to know why that happens, but finding a solution wasn't so easy. You can't add a variable outside of `plugins {}` because it won't be reachable. One way would be to have a static field in your `buildSrc` folder, but it would be weird needing it only for that.

Here's something I found that works. In your root `build.gradle.kts` add:

```
plugins {
    id("ru.vyarus.quality") version "4.3.0" apply false
}

project(":yourModule") {
    if (gradle.gradleVersion < "6.0") {
        apply(plugin = "ru.vyarus.qualit")
    }
}
```

I wish it didn't need the old `apply(plugin =` way, but that's the only solution I found. You don't need anything special in your module's `plugins {}`.